# After sending the email clear the data from text fields in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am beginner in MVC and trying to clear the data from text fields after sending the email. I have sent the email successfully but data is not removing after sending the email. I have tried many solutions, but I am not getting the good results. So, what should I do?

**Create.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group" id="name">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="email">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="comment">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg comments" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="success" type="submit" value="Get In Touch" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg btn-login" />
            @*<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" onclick="SendEmail()" >click to send email</a>*@
        </div>
```

**FeedbacksController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Comments")] Feedback feedback)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bool result = false;
        db.Feedbacks.Add(feedback);
        db.SaveChanges();
        result = SendEmail("abc@gmail.com", "Feedback", "<p>Hi Admin,<br/>My name is "+ feedback.Name + ". <br/> E_mail ID: " + feedback.Email + "<br/><br/>" + feedback.Comments + "<br/>Kind Regards,<br/>" + feedback.Name + "</p>");

        return View( );
    }
    return View(feedback);
}
```

Comment: Follow the PRG pattern and use `return RedirectToAction("Create");` (not `return View();`)

Comment: You can reset the model properties before returning the view

Comment: @SouvikGhosh How can I do it?

Comment: Probably your model is `Feedback`. So you need to set `Feedback.Name = ""; Feedback.Email = ""; Feedback.Comments = "";` and then `return View(feedback);`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh, That will not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Server side**

Add this code after send email in action

```
 ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: So in case the email is not sent successfully, the form fields would get reset.

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh add `ModelState.Clear();` before `return View()`